# How to plot a 2D figure form a 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, plot, slice

I want to plot a 2D figure which is a plane-cut from a 4D array.
for example:

```
In[1]:
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [3, 4, 5]
z = [6, 7, 8]
f = [9, 10, 11]
X, Y, Z, F = meshgrid(x, y, z, f)  #create 4D grid


Out[1]:
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]]])

In[2]:
A = X + 1j*Y + Z + 1j* F

Out[2]:
array([[[[  6.+12.j,   6.+13.j,   6.+14.j],
         [  7.+12.j,   7.+13.j,   7.+14.j],
         [  8.+12.j,   8.+13.j,   8.+14.j]],

        [[  7.+12.j,   7.+13.j,   7.+14.j],
         [  8.+12.j,   8.+13.j,   8.+14.j],
         [  9.+12.j,   9.+13.j,   9.+14.j]],

        [[  8.+12.j,   8.+13.j,   8.+14.j],
         [  9.+12.j,   9.+13.j,   9.+14.j],
         [ 10.+12.j,  10.+13.j,  10.+14.j]]],


       [[[  6.+13.j,   6.+14.j,   6.+15.j],
         [  7.+13.j,   7.+14.j,   7.+15.j],
         [  8.+13.j,   8.+14.j,   8.+15.j]],

        [[  7.+13.j,   7.+14.j,   7.+15.j],
         [  8.+13.j,   8.+14.j,   8.+15.j],
         [  9.+13.j,   9.+14.j,   9.+15.j]],

        [[  8.+13.j,   8.+14.j,   8.+15.j],
         [  9.+13.j,   9.+14.j,   9.+15.j],
         [ 10.+13.j,  10.+14.j,  10.+15.j]]],


       [[[  6.+14.j,   6.+15.j,   6.+16.j],
         [  7.+14.j,   7.+15.j,   7.+16.j],
         [  8.+14.j,   8.+15.j,   8.+16.j]],

        [[  7.+14.j,   7.+15.j,   7.+16.j],
         [  8.+14.j,   8.+15.j,   8.+16.j],
         [  9.+14.j,   9.+15.j,   9.+16.j]],

        [[  8.+14.j,   8.+15.j,   8.+16.j],
         [  9.+14.j,   9.+15.j,   9.+16.j],
         [ 10.+14.j,  10.+15.j,  10.+16.j]]]])
```

Now the shape of A is

```
(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Now my question is how to plot 2D figure from this 4D array which is (Y=0 and F = 0), and is this the right way to plot a plane-cut from a 4D figure?

Answer (score 0):

A plane cut with the shape `n x m` from a spacial figure in 3D grids (surf plot) may be plotted using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`. If it is not a surf plot, however, you may use `plot`, but you have to calculate the contour of your figure from the desired dimensions.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show

imshow(variable, interpolation='none')
show()
```

The shape may also adjusted as follows:

```
# Given |variable| is an object of type numpy.array:

var_reshaped = variable.reshape(int(variable.size/2), -1)
```

This creates a square-shaped output from the data. You should be vigilant when reshaping an array to ensure that the integrity of the shape is not compromised. That is, you must make sure `m x n` of your reshaped array is identical to the two dimensions you're extracting your plane from (any double combination of x, y or z).

Also, you cannot take a plane directly from 4D. You must extract a 3D array first, and then a 2D one. For instance, imagine an MRI with 10 exposures (4D: 10 x 50 x 50 x 50). You must first extract one exposure (3D: 50 x 50 x 50), and then attempt to display that a slice (2D: 50 x 50).